# What is the best way to be aware of the loss of precision when converting a usize to a f64 in Rust?

Tags: rust

This code:

```
use std::usize;

fn main() {
    fn main() {
    let a = usize::MAX;
    println!("{:?}", a );
    println!("{:?}", a as f64 );
}
```

returns

```
18446744073709551615
18446744073709552000
```

what is the best way to be aware of this loss of precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`conv`](https://crates.io/crates/conv) crate was designed to handle this.  The `ValueFrom`/`ValueInto` traits perform value-preserving conversions that will return an error if the input value cannot be exactly represented in the output type.  For example:

````rust
/*!
Add this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```cargo
[dependencies]
conv = "0.3.2"
```
*/
extern crate conv;

use conv::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let a = std::u32::MAX;
    println!("u32::MAX -> f32: {:?}", a.value_as::<f32>());
    println!("u32::MAX -> f64: {:?}", a.value_as::<f64>());
}
````

Outputs:

```
u32::MAX -> f32: Err(PosOverflow(..))
u32::MAX -> f64: Ok(4294967295)
```

Alternately, you can replicate the checking `conv` does by hand: check that the input integer does not fall outside the range of integers the floating point type can exactly represent.  Specifically:

- `f32`: ±16,777,215
- `f64`: ±9,007,199,254,740,991

Answer (score 4):

Well, 64-bit floating point representation is accurate to [15–17 significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), so you can estimate potential inaccuracy based on that. You *could* get more fancy to saying that such-and-such a float representation has a margin of error of `x`, so that that particular bit sequence represents values in the range `self - x` to `self + x`, but that’s so rarely a useful concept that you won’t be likely to find much code to assist you on it.